# Ubuntu - Django installation issue

Tags: django, ubuntu, middleware

I've installed Django on fresh ubuntu server.
I'm trying to run simple app by mod_python, and I get following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.messages.middleware: "No module named messages.middleware"
```

Sometimes it raise:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.template.loaders.filesystem" does not define a "Loader" callable template source loader
```

How can I get rid of that errors?

Comment: Step 1: Stop using mod_python.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using mod_wsgi, mod_python should no longer be used.

Comment: On mod_wsgi I got: "ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.template.loaders.filesystem" does not define a "Loader" callable template source loader"